# fill a bootstrap column with multiple span elements having dynamic number in multiple lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, flexbox

as the title suggests I have a div with bootstrap class="column" and I'm trying to fill it with some span elements.notice that this span elements don't have a fixed number.
my column has a fixed width but the spans can break into more than one line.so if there are too many elements or the user zooms in, the spans will be shown in multiple lines.
here's the tricky part: I want the spans in each line to stretch and fill the line. is it possible? I tried stayle="display : flex" but flex makes spans go out of line if they are too much.
(sorry I don't have a fiddle since the code is a bit messy and complicated)
here's a demonstration where the <> are spans and spaces:

```
|---------------------------|
|<aaaaaaaaa><ddddddddd><fff>|
|<sdf><sdfsd><sdf ><sdfsdf >|
|<   sd   ><   sdf   >< sd >|
|---------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You place `span`s inside a column with `text-align:justify` and give `span` elements `display:inline-block`.

The trick to make the last line's elements to align properly is to use an `:after` pseudo-element on the column and give it the following code:

```
.col:after {
  content: "";
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This essentially forces another line to be created, so the previous line - last line of `span`s will be justified.

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3kem9asp/3/

Edit: I changed inline-block to table for the :after pseudo element, to clear the last line.

Comment: thanks, but that's not exactly what i was asking for. my spans have background color ( different for each one) and I need them to fill the column(so there is no white background seen).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer. I clearly wanted to write something else, I just woke up :)

Comment: thanks :) this one works fine. is there a way to also make the spans stretch so there is no space between them?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean ...it is not possible to have the content fit exactly. I also added some padding in the spans, maybe you want to remove that? Unless you mean something else..? Edit: Updated fiddle, check now?

Comment: for example in the last line there are 5 spans, I want them to cover all the line they are in.so if they have a background color - let's say #777 - almost all the line will have that color and not white.

Comment: What you are asking can be 'faked'. Check the followin fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3kem9asp/4/ I added another pseudo element and positioned it absolutely at the position where the last line is, and added relative positioning to the spans to make sure that they are placed on top of it.

Comment: Since your problem is solved, please select the checkmark under the original reply to select this as the right answer.

Comment: actually there's one more little detail. the spans don't have the same color. so I can't use exactly your workaround and still need an answer for that.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean?

Comment: there are multiple spans each with a color of it's own (which I read from some database). so I can't 'fake' it since it would be obvious that I am using another element to color the background. I don't want to change the background color,in fact I don't want the background to be seen at all, I want the spans to fill the div.

Comment: I am not sure that what you are asking can be done without some heavy js

Comment: Ok. thanks for your time and effort. I concluded the same.

Comment: Thanks for the points of confidence.Good luck with your project!